# Best way to run an async job or operation upon Vapor app startup?

Tags: swift, vapor

I have a Vapor app, and what I want to accomplish is this - upon app startup, I want to run an async job or some kind of async operation that can clear out and re-dispatch some dispatched jobs. I want to do this upon app startup, in case the app has been down for maintenance or migrations.

I suppose I could create a scheduled job, and schedule it for shortly after now or something, but is that the best way?

Answer (score 1):

First add the queues capability to your `Package.swift` in dependencies:

```swift
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/queues.git", from: "1.0.0"),
.package(url: "https://github.com/m-barthelemy/vapor-queues-fluent-driver.git", from: "1.0.0-rc.2")
```

Then add it to your `App` target dependencies:

```swift
.product(name: "Queues", package: "queues"),
.product(name: "QueuesFluentDriver", package: "vapor-queues-fluent-driver"),
```

Then, the easiest way is to dispatch a job in `configure.swift`, but first add the definition of the job and start up the queues:

```swift
import Fluent
import Queues

app.queues.use(.fluent())
app.queues.add(OnBootJob())
try app.queues.startInProcessJobs(on: .default)
app.queues.queue.dispatch(OnBootJob.self, .init(something: "blah"))
```

Here is a skeleton job:

```swift
struct OnBootPayload: Codable {
    let something: String
}

struct OnWeeklyDemandJob: AsyncJob {
    typealias Payload = OnBootPayload

    func dequeue(_ context: QueueContext, _ payload: Payload) async throws {
        context.application.db.logger.notice("onBoot started")
        // The real work gets done here
    }
}
```